# React filtering cards

Tags: reactjs, filtering

I built an app calling an API. Now trying to build the search bar but the filtering doesn't seem to work and I'm not sure what's wrong inside the filter function...

Here's the render:

```
render() {
        const { search, allCards } = this.state;

        const filterCards = allCards.filter(card => {
            return card.awardYear.includes(search.toLowerCase) !== -1;
        })

        let cards = filterCards.map((card) => {
            return <WinnerCard
                key={card.id}
                awardYear={card.awardYear}
                category={card.category.en}
                name={card.laureates[0].knownName?.en}
                motivation={card.laureates[0].motivation?.en}
            />
        });
```

And the return:

```
return (
            <div>
                <div>
                        <Form.Control
                            type="text"
                            placeholder=""
                            className="col-4 font-weight-bold border-dark"
                            value={this.state.search}
                            onChange={this.onChange}
                        />
                    </Form>
                </div>
                <div>
                    {cards}
                </div>
            </div>
        )
```

Any help is welcome!

Comment: which filter is not working? the first one or the second?

Comment: Did you want to use `.indexOf()` instead of `.includes()`?

Comment: what's your result?

Answer (score 1):

`String.prototype.includes` returns a boolean value, not a number (see [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)). So instead of comparing `card.awardYear.includes(search.toLowerCase)` to -1, just check if it's `true`. So the filter function in your code when fixed, would be:

```
const filterCards = allCards.filter(card => 
  card.awardYear.includes(search.toLowerCase)
)
```